# SmartStore.net installation dramas

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, iis-8

I'm having an issue running a new project...

It's Smartstore.net version 2.x source downloaded and unzipped to local dev machine (win 8.1 running iis 8.5)

create new website in iis pointing to "SmartStoreNET-2.x\src\Presentation\SmartStore.Web"

setup hosts file etc and set permissions on appdata, content, media, plugins

configured VS21012 web proj to use iis website created previously.

build sln, all good.

run sln ctrl+F5 and recieve "503 Service Unavailable" from browser as the app pool has shut down from too many errors. what errors?

if i run without using iis and use the inbuilt webserver in VS then it runs but the .less fails and there's no css. is there some .less plugin i'm missing?

any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum IDE requirement for SmartStore.NET is Visual Studio 2013. You should better try again with VS 2015 Community Edition.